# Form styling - why do my inputs spill out of the form?

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm trying to establish a certain amount of padding within the cells holding my inputs, and within the text inputs themselves so that the text doesn't butt up against the sides.  I've set the input widths to 100%, and yet for some reason they extend beyond the width of the form. Can anyone explain why?

```css
form {  
 color: #000000;  
 font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
 width:100%;
}

form table {    
  background-color: #F9FBFD;    
  color: #000000;    
  width: 100%;    
  border: 1px solid #D7E5F2;    
  border-collapse: collapse;    
}    

form table td {  
  border: 1px solid #D7E5F2;  
  padding: 4px 8px;  
}

input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #999;   
    padding:2px 4px;
}
```

```html
<form id="signup" name="signup" method="post" action="#">  
                          <table>  
                            <tr>    
                              <td ><label for="name">Name</label></td>  
                              <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name" tabindex="1"  /></td>  
                            </tr>  
                           
                            <tr>    
                              <td><label for="email">Email *</label></td>  
                              <td><input type="text" id="email" name="email" tabindex="2" /></td>  
                            </tr>  
                            
                            <tr>    
                              <td class="top"><label for="topic">Your Message</label></td>  
                              <td><textarea id="comment" name="comment" tabindex="3" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea></td>  
                            </tr>  
                            
                            <tr>    
                              <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send" tabindex="8" /></td>  
                            </tr>  
                          </table>  
                        </form>
```

This [example](http://jsfiddle.net/a7u8N/1/) was the original reference.

Comment: Your question is still not well constructed. Lay out the problem before the sharing the code. Beyond the ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) advice, you also need to start by stating the question in a way that focuses on what gap remains _after_ your research. Describe [step like these](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-debug-any-problem-ac6f8a867fae) that you have done thus far, for code, conditions, and errors. State 'obvious' context that you already know, [so that people understand what you have tried](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: You have a super-high rep, so maybe this was just one of your first questions?

Comment: 2011. I was just a babe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is how padding/width work... padding actually contributes to the width, so when you define the width of the input as 100%, it is 100% of its parent.. when you add a padding of 4px left and right, your input width is now 100% of parent + 8px.

You can compensate for this by adding the difference of the width and padding (8px in this example) to the parents padding:

```
form table td {  
  border: 1px solid #D7E5F2;  
  padding: 4px 16px 4px 8px; 
}
```

Note, the right had side padding is now the original 8px it had before PLUS the 8px extra width that the input element contained... 16px total :)

Also note, this method doesnt reduce the padding within your input elements, just compensates for it :)

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/a7u8N/3/

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this is happening, as others suggest, is because width:100% causes the width of the input to match that of the parent element. Padding and borders added to the input are in addition to the width, and are not included as part of it - thus you get an input that overall exceeds the width of the parent element.

I'd recommend reading up on how the box model works, as it's important in understanding this particular problem and also good to know for working with CSS layouts in general.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the effect by 4 pixels using this instead:

```
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-left: 4px;
```

That removes the bottom padding and right padding which don't really apply in the first place.